# pycharm :No module named 'tvm'

Tags: python, pycharm, tvm

I want to use tvm in my project,but got "pycharm :No module named 'tvm'". And I have configurated tvm.If I use the terminal environment to run the project, I can successful run program. The main problem is I need the hint in the pycharm.I try to add the system environment in pycharm, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Make sure PyCharm project is configured to use the same Python interpreter / virtual environment as "your terminal"

Comment: I have better luck using virtual environments in PyCharm.  I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

In PyCharm, in Project Settings, you can choose Python Interpreter.

You need to set this to point to the same `python` or `python.exe` command you run in a terminal. Otherwise PyCharm will use some (other) Python interpreter installed on your computer.

In UNIX shell you can find out which `python` command is run by your terminal by typing `which python`.